# Do I need to manually remove all event to make my object remove from memory?

Tags: .net, asp.net, events, c#-2.0

I have read in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(VS.80).aspx) that is require to Unsubscribing every events an object has to be able to dispose it from memory. I always used -= to remove all references to event inside my object (like MSDN show).

Now, I have to maintain code and it has some memory leak on it. I see that the previous developer simply set the object that has all events subscribes on it to NULL and do not -= every event method.

Example:

```
_watcher.Changed += new ...
_watcher.Created += new ...
_watcher.Deleted += ..

//later.

_watcher = NULL;
```

Is it a good way or does it keeps the variable in memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345130/do-i-need-to-unsubscribe-from-manually-subscribed-to-events-in-asp-net

Comment: @ChrisF: not exactly. There are talking specially for ASP.NET. This seems to be a more general .NET question.

Comment: I need to know for general use of .net. The problem occur in a Windows Service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are no other references to `_watcher`, then there is no need to remove the event handlers to avoid a memory leak.

As a matter of habit I tend to explicitly remove event handlers.

Comment: Correct. As long as there's no strong reference to the object itself, the object will be GCed and the event handlers automatically unsubscribed. MSDN isn't very clear on this...

Comment: @Noldorin: yeah, I always have to think twice about it!